# Change country for a way in openStreetMap

Tags: openstreetmap

After having downloaded the country specific map details from the OSM server we have seen some problems where some railway ways are considered as Hungarian in the database but in fact there are Ukrainian.

How to change the country tag of a point or way?
Within the map editor I do not see any possibility to do that.

Comment: Can you provider more details? The railway way you are talking about, the source of the map data, the tools you are using to determine the country etc.

Comment: Like I've answered below we have maid our own tile server for displaying the railways for Hungary and we have seen some discrepancies in the database (There are data which should not be there as there are (far) outside of the country boundary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The country is defined by an [administrative boundary relation](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Relation:boundary) with a corresponding [admin_level](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:boundary%3Dadministrative#admin_level) tag (as an example see [relation 60199](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/60199) - the administrative boundary of Ukraine). The country is *not* an attribute of a way.

This means either the administrative border of Ukraine is wrong at the area in question, or the tools you are using are wrong, or you did use them wrong.

Comment: Normally you might be write but in that particular case we have a railway portion which is appearing in the hungary.osm file but it is quite behind the Ukrainian border. This is not a single case, I have several cases like this.

Comment: Where did you get the hungary.osm file?

Comment: download.geofabrik.de. There I can find the daily refresh of the country specific data

Comment: As far as I know the data does not get cropped at the border. That is, if the railway *way* crosses the border then it will be fully contained in both extracts.

Comment: Unfortunately in this particular case the way starts and ends "deep" inside Ukraine, i.e. the railway way is NOT crossing the border. I don't know whether you can see that, but if you  have a look on this map: http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=14/48.1814/22.6557&layers=Q the railway right below the road M-23 is the the Hungarian database and it should not be there

Comment: [way 127240942](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/127240942) *almost* crosses the border (minimum distance seems to be around 50 m). Maybe that's already the reason, it might be possible that Geofabrik adds a very small buffer around the border when creating extracts. It would be the best to contact Geofabrik directly or re-ask your question at http://help.openstreetmap.org/. But don't forget to include a link to this question when cross-posting.

Comment: All right! This is then the answer. Too bad, but we will try to display only the ways which are exclusively/mostly in Hungary. Thanks for your help.